# If $ac-bd \not= 0$, then $(ax+by) \ \cap \ (cx+dy) \ \subseteq \ (x^2,xy,y^2)?$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

I have a very simple ring theoretic question I got stuck on:

> Let $k$ be a field and consider the polynomial ring $k[x,y]$.
>   Let $a,b,c,d \in k$ such that $ac-bd \not= 0$. Establish the following containment of ideals:
>   $$
> (ax+by) \ \cap \ (cx+dy) 
> \quad \subseteq \quad
> (x^2,xy,y^2).
> $$

The ideal $(ax+by) \ \cap \ (cx+dy) $ can be interpreted as polynomials $f(x,y)$ that vanish on two dictinct lines through the origin. The right hand has some strange scheme-theoretic intuition that I find hard to grasp.

My skills in commutative algebra are to weak to solve this. I don't see how to write an element $f(x,y)$ in the intersection as a someting of the form 
$
x^2 p(x,y) + xy q(x,y) + y^2r(x,y).
$
Could you please give me some hints?

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ In a GCD domain: $\ (f)\cap (g) = ({\rm lcm}(f,g))\,$  and $\,\gcd(f,g) = 1\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm lcm}(f,g) = fg.\  \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just unique factorisation in $k[x,y]$. The elements $f=ax+by$ and $g=cx+dy$
are irreducible and non-associate as long as $ad-bc\ne0$. Therefore if
$f$ and $g$ both divide a polynomial $h$, then $fg$ also divides $h$.

Comment: I often get confused about this. The property $f,g | h \ \Rightarrow \ fg | h$ is not equivalent to $f,g$ being coprime?

Answer (score 4):

This is obvious if you know the basics of the dictionary translating ring theory into affine scheme theory:

The required inclusion of ideals $$
(ax+by)  \cap  (cx+dy) 
 \subset (x^2,xy,y^2) $$ is equivalent to the  opposite inclusion of subschemes of $\mathbb A^2_k\:$   $$ V(ax+by) \cup V(cx+dy)\supset V(x^2,xy,y^2).$$ And that inclusion is clear because any curve singular at the origin (in our case the union of the two distinct lines $V(ax+by), V(cx+dy)$)   contains the first infinitesimal neighbourhood $V(x^2,xy,y^2)$ of the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are already hints, let me complete the details of the solution. As Lord Shark the Unknown wrote, it's easy to see that both $ax+by$ and $cx+dy$ are irreducible in $k[x,y]$ and as $ad-bc\neq 0$, then both are non-associates.

Now, $k[x, y]$ is a UFD, so in particular is a [GCD domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain). It follows then that $\gcd (ax+by, cx+dy)=1$. Since $$(ax+by)(cx+dy)=\gcd (ax+by, cx+dy)\text{lcm}(ax+by, cx+dy)$$ we deduce that $\text{lcm}(ax+by, cx+dy)=(ax+by)(cx+dy)=acx^2+(ad+bc)xy+bdy^2$.

Therefore, we deduce that $$(ax+by)\cap (cx+dy)=(acx^2+(ad+bc) xy+bdy^2). $$ Now, it's clear that $ acx^2+(ad+bc) xy+bdy^2\in (x^2,xy, y^2) $. Hence $$(ax+by)\cap (cx+dy)\subseteq (x^2, xy, y^2).$$